# Context Menu for ListView that contains radio buttons

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu, android-radiobutton

I have a listview with a custom adapter, and a row layout. The row consists of a textview, imageview and a radio button. After implementing the method I am unable to obtain the position of the clicked view.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    Log.d("menuinfo: ",""+menuInfo); //This returns null
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select action");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_testing, menu);
}
```

I think the culprit is the radio button, but it's an essential part of the listview and I cannot remove it. Any workaround and suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the row which has been clicked from the adapter class itself

```
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener,OnBufferingUpdateListener{

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          View vi = convertView;

         crntposition=position;

          if(convertView==null){

              Context context=arg2.getContext();
               inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                       getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlistrow, null);

        // vi.setTag(R.id.parentlay, holder.parnt); 
     }

// your code 

 vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(crntposition));

        return vi;

    }

private class OnItemClickListener  implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position) {

            mPosition = position;

            //System.out.println("pos"+mPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


          System.out.println("current position"+mPosition);// you can use the position here I have just printed it

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your adapter, set  radiobutton view's tag as the currentPosition by using

```
     yourbutton.setTag(position).
```

Then set onCheckedChangeListener on the radioButton.

In the onCheckedChaged method of the listener, you get the button for which the state has been changed. From that button, do

```
   yourButton.getTag(),
```

this will give you the position that this radiobutton belongs to..
See if it works.